Falling object into cloth simulation not working
im trying to simulate this object falling into a cloth and making nice ripples in it but I cant get it right, the cloth keeps going through the object no matter what. and the other problem is that I started with subdividing the cloth plane by 50 first to make playback quicker and then doubled it to 100 but it has these sharp bending in the faces when the object falls into it. i attached an image because its hard to explain.

I beg for someone to help me.

Those are the ripples, the divisions are still too big and you didn't add a shade smooth to the cloth.

Things that might affect the result: apply the scales, check the face orientations and do a merge by distance

My answer is inspired by this tuto by uc studio: Give a Soft Body then a Collision physic to your solid object, in the Soft Body panel, under Edges, set the Pull, Push and Bending values to their maximum. Give a Soft Body then a Collision physic to your cloth object, enable its Collisions and Self Collisions options. Result:

